# collapsing ruby objects in a hash

Tags: ruby, hash

I have an object which looks likes this:

```
[{"amount":"500.0","when":"2012-03-13"},
 {"amount":"500.0","when":"2012-03-24"},
 {"amount":"100.0","when":"2012-04-14"},
 {"amount":"100.0","when":"2012-04-16"}]
```

I would like to get it back as

```
 [{"amount":"1000.0","when":"2012-03"},
 {"amount":"200.0","when":"2012-04"}]
```

Is there an elegant way of doing it? I have a version that works but it's really crappy looking

```
@exps = Expense.find(:all, :select => ["`when`", "amount"])  
@exp_month = {}
@result = []

@exps.each do |e|
  month = "#{e.when.year}-#{e.when.month}"
  @exp_month[month] = @exp_month.has_key?(month) ? @exp_month[month] + e.amount : e.amount     
end

@exp_month.keys.each do |m|    
  @result << {"when" => m, "amount" => @exp_month[m]}
end
```

Comment: I'm not clear on what you are trying to do exactly. Add up the amounts of the items in the hash per two items?

Comment: Add up amounts by month.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming that you've unpacked your JSON into a Ruby Array of Hashes:

```
a = [
    {:amount => "500.0", :when => "2012-03-13"},
    {:amount => "500.0", :when => "2012-03-24"},
    {:amount => "100.0", :when => "2012-04-14"},
    {:amount => "100.0", :when => "2012-04-16"}
]
```

Then you could do this:

```
compressed = a.group_by { |h| h[:when][0,7] }.map do |k, v|
    {
        :when   => k,
        :amount => v.inject(0) { |i, h| i + h[:amount].to_i }
    }
end
```

That would leave you with this in `compressed`:

```
[
    {:when => "2012-03", :amount => 1000},
    {:when => "2012-04", :amount => 200}
]
```

And you can convert that to JSON in the usual way.

The `group_by` chunks the original array using only the year and month components. Then you just have to rearrange things and sum a slice of the grouped Hashes using `map` and `inject`.

Comment: I was going for the same thing, you beat me to it!  I'd suggest a more robust month grouping though: `group_by {|h| Date.strptime(h[:when]).strftime("%Y-%m")`

Comment: @JonM: If the dates aren't in ISO-8601 format then you'll have to give `strptime` a format string and if the dates are in ISO-8601 format then string wrangling is fine. If you had the possibility of `2012-2-4` then going through Date would be useful, or you could adjust the string wrangling. Six of one, half a dozen of the other :)